# How can I approximate having a static variable in an Inner class?

Tags: java, static, abstract-class, processing

I am working on a series of classes that all inherit from a single, base, abstract class.

In order to keep track of all of these child classes, I'd like to implement something like a GUID -- for my purposes, it doesn't have to be an actual GUID, just an int that is unique to each instance of a child class. An incremented int is what I'd been hoping to use.

What I'd have liked to do, is implement the following in my abstract class:

```
abstract class ParentObject{

   static int GUID = 0;

   //other stuff

}
```

whereafter each child class, in its constructor, would have `myGUID = GUID++;`

However, whenever I try this, I get the following error from the Processing IDE:

> The field GUID cannot be declared static; static fields can only be
>   declared in static or top-level types.

Because of how Processing handles class files (everything is an inner class), I can't have static class members. What are my options to duplicate this functionality in other ways?

**Edit:** This is being done in Processing and the Processing IDE. The ParentObject class **is** in its own processing file.

**Edite2:** I have learned that the reason Processing is different from Java is that all Processing classes are Inner Classes. Because of this, I have re-added the Java tag and reformulated the question.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, is there any benefit to having the parent class itself be Abstract in this case? If I just change all the methods / parameters to be abstract instead, it shouldn't muck up the inheritance trees...

Comment: My java compiler (`javac 1.6.0_26`) accepts that code just fine. What are you using exactly?

Comment: My compiler `1.7.0` also accepts this.

Comment: Eclipse allows it too and it works just fine.

Comment: If your `myGUID` is non-static, then each child *instance* would have a varying value, depending on when it was created. Rather, wouldn't you want a static child *class* variable for each derived class>

Comment: Firstly, you need to move the abstract class into its own file (you must have it as a static inner class to get that message). Secondly, this approach is *NOT THREAD SAFE* - two objects can get *the same* value with your code. Consider using AtomicInteger instead.

Comment: @KerrekSB - no, I want a unique int per *instance*, because I can have  multiple instances of the same class class at once, and I want to keep them straight.

Comment: @GregHewgill - I am using Processing, and the Processing IDE.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - OP edited. Ping!

Comment: @Voo - unfortunately, I'm not using Eclipse.

Comment: Okay. I've removed the `java` tag from this question, because Processing is not Java.

Comment: @GregHewgill - Wait, what? Processing is basically a highly customized java library, is it not?

Comment: If your compiler doesn't accept that code, then the language you are using is not Java. It's close, but not the real thing.

Comment: Well, not really, there are some differences in Processing and Java. Pure Java accepts your code fine.

Comment: @SHiRKiT Not if you put the code in an inner class (which is what this code effectively is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, then face it. You can't do it. If you REALLY need it, declare an outer class for handling this piece of code, and call it in the top-level class's constructor.

If you MUST use this hierarchy of innerclass, then you can't do it. Java won't accept it in the way you wan't. You could declare your abstract class as static.

```
static abstract class ParentObject {

    private static int GUID = 0;

}
```

But I'm almost sure this won't work for you either. So, I suggest to create a new outer class somewhere else to handle it.

```
public class GUID {

    private static int GUID = 0;

    public synchronized static void increment() {
        GUID++;
    }
}

abstract class ParentObject {

    ParentObject() {

        GUID.increment();

        // constructor's stuff
    }

}
```

This may speed down your app (depending on how often you instantiate a class), but not in a significant way.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm just going to move out of the Processing IDE. It's giving me all kinds of awful.

Answer (score 0):

a static protected method getNextGUID() would work

```
public abstract class ParentObject{

   private static int GUID = 0;

   protected static int getNextGUID(){
       return GUID++;
   }
   //other stuff

}
```

don't forget to synchronize it/use AtomicInteger when you have multiple threads

Comment: If the language doesn't allow static variables in abstract classes I fear that approach also wouldn't work. Actually I don't see any reasonable way to solve that problem with that limitation (if a static final variable is allowed we can use a wrapper class)